# Official Slack Channel

Tags: discussion

With the growing popularity of [Slack](https://slack.com/) especially in [its relationship to Salesforce](https://techcrunch.com/2016/09/27/enterprise-chat-app-slack-ties-up-with-salesforce-in-a-deep-platform-partnership/), I'm curious if there has been talk or any interest in starting an official Salesforce community team essentially like [WordPress did](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) as its official IRC. This could be a great way to network and support some of the common best practice ideas.

I am tempted to start the team myself but at the moment I feel like this forum is the strongest pulse of the community and wanted to see if there is any interest or any reasons why this doesn't already exist. Perhaps we could setup http://salesforcecommunity.slack.com

Comment: I'm not sure what slack provides that we can't get on chat here? Isn't there a pricing element involved?

Comment: The free-tier provides the ability to setup channels and support many users, the admins just won't have the ability to set roles to manage access to specific channels (but private channels can still be established). The chat here is very inaccessible in my opinion, many people don't realize it exist and its rare that you are on when others are so the conversation never happens. Exhibit A: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52102/apex-enterprise-patterns

Comment: Communication to me is lifeblood of any group, and the best tool is simply the one that works. I've constantly experienced that slack does work which is why its trending the way it is. And with several free integrations we could even integrate how it works with this forum

Comment: I saw that one. I'm all for it as long as I don't have to do any of the work! :P I think part of establishing chat here is just getting a regular room going where we can just...chat. Doesn't have to be on topic. Keep enough people around and the conversation will move.

Comment: I've started several teams but never a public one so I'm just not sure at the moment how to make it publicly accessible and convenient the way WordPress did (but I can figure it out)

Comment: One major downsides of the sfse chat rooms has been that they get frozen or archived after a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an experiment I went ahead and set up a public slack team with multiple channels to help foster community dialog. If you would like to try it out join us with the link below:

**Team Slack Domain**: `SalesforceCommunity`

**Direct URL**: [`http://SalesforceCommunity.slack.com`](http://SalesforceCommunity.slack.com)

> **GETTING STARTED:**

If you're new to [image] Slack be sure to check out the **#slack-help** channel once you're in.

Also if you have multiple teams that you're part of and would like to distinguish this team from your others, try out the *custom sidebar theme* by clicking on **Preferences > Sidebar Theme** and under "custom theme" paste the following:

**Grey Theme**

```
#6c6c6c,#333333,#01a3d6,#FFFFFF,#4682b4,#FFFFFF,#e8673e,#008080
```

**Blue Theme:**

```
#4682B4,#34648f,#28B7E5,#FFFFFF,#28B7E5,#ffffff,#e8673e,#E8673E
```

---

### UPDATE: Workspace Migrating to "Good Day, Sir!"

> Although I still really support this concept and the Slack platform, I never had the time to invest in the community to help it thrive as I imagined (#busyness). With 86 members I'm planning to close the org by the end of the year (2019) and encourage users to **join me on the ["Good Day, Sir! Community"](https://gooddaysir.typeform.com/to/eLl6bf) workspace**, they have nearly 1k users and are a very active community with a weekly podcast that continues to spark conversation and healthy community. I really respect what Jeremy Ross & John De Santiago are doing for the community and they've attracted some great contributors, including some key Salesforce staff. Hope to see you there!

Answer (score 12):

I'm a bit hesitant about promoting something like an off channel Slack for Salesforce.

One of the strengths of the StackExchange is that everything is kept out in the open where it can be commented on and refined over time. Sure you could ask a question and get an answer in either Slack or here. But on SFSE the Q&A will hang around on the internet to be indexed and provide help to countless others over time. So many times I've been saved by Googling a problem I've had in the past and found the posts here.

There is a reason chat and other forms of direct communication aren't promoted on StackExchange, they don't really serve the community as a whole.

What I've often seen with Slack is all the useful information disappearing over time. Particularly with the free tier where you only have limited storage.

That's just my 2 cents based on what I'm seeing in other slack channels.

Comment: I get that, and agree posting of questions should still happen here, even in WordPress community they direct all questions back to the forum, but several times I've been able to get added commentary about a question, or see conversations from WP's MVPs (sorta a speak) to be more aware of the platform I'm developing on rather than just the language. Also would be nice to personally connect with developers in my region or with similar challenges

Comment: I've always liked twitter for general Salesforce community chat. It isn't as rich as Slack but avoids the walled garden of unindexed content problem. I do like Slack for internal company chatter, but that is the sort of inane stuff that shouldn't be indexed - like: "There is cake in the lunch room!"

Comment: When we started #OhanaSlack, we considered a Salesforce Community as well - but Slack won. What we really wanted was a way to get faster more responsive help. I'm on Twitter regularly through the day and when i ask or answer questions it's hard - the character limit Makes what you can ask limited or makes numerous posts, or lots of bad answers from missing info/incomplete descriptions/responses. Or you end up DMing a d nobody else sees the answer and it's like whatever happened when you find it on Google.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older post but ran across it on Google - thought I would share access to another fantabulous Salesforce Slack resource. 
You are all welcome to join #OhanaSlack. We recently passed 1k members, I started the Workspace 2 years ago with a co-worker to have a space for real time help with questions with the Community, and we've grown from there. the space is global, we have channels for everything now practically and it grows based on what people need and know, from why admins drink to each cloud to Lightning dev, Road to CTA, study groups, files, etc. The space is for Admins, Devs, Architects, and Consultants - some Salesforce employees as well. 
There is just something about having that real-time dialogue that makes a difference. You can easily go back and forth or jump on a screen share when needed and get an answer right then and there. Being global helps when it's that crazy hour - there's always someone around. Plus, so many of us are on slack already, it's usually already open.
Here's my recent blog post about the Workspace, rules are listed here too. We have a strict anti-spamming, anti-recruting (outside of the #careers and #freelance channels) and anti-selling rules - 2nd time you're removed: https://mrockssf.site/OhanaSlack
Here's the sign up link: https://mrockssf.site/2UerYNG

Looking forward to seeing you there!

Answer (score 2):

For now, in an effort to make chat *on this platform* more popular and useful, I've started a chat room inspired by the Teachers' Lounge moderator chat room. I couldn't think of a great name, but for now I just titled it [Open Office Hours](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53431/open-office-hours). Come join! Talk about whatever suits your mood! No politics though.

This is new territory for me as well but I think with chat it's about establishing a *culture*. Here's one small step. I'm very open to feedback about how to change this room to make chat more popular. The more people that use it, the more useful it becomes.

Comment: Hey Adrian, can we restart Open Office Hours? Its more open platform than Slack or   Discord that I have seen people using.