# 25th Most Visited SE Site on the network, still post counts are decreasing yearly?

Tags: discussion

Matt Lacey mentioned about [We're the 25th most visited site on the network](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/were-the-25th-most-visited-site-on-the-network)

This made me curious to run a query regarding the number of posts made yearly. And to my surpise, it looks like that number is going down.

```
SELECT count(Id) as count ,  datepart(yyyy, CreationDate) as year 
FROM Posts group by datepart(yyyy, CreationDate) order by year
```

[image]

I am trying to figure out what can be a reason for it? Is SFSE dreaded like SO? or we have answered most of the questions that answers can be found just by googling that people don't post here?

Query : https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/1086109

**Edit**: As requested for votes

[image]

Votes Querry: https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/1086566/votes-by-year

Comment: Can you query number of upvotes per year .. That can tell us whether users are able to find answers or not

Comment: @ManjotSingh added for Votes

Comment: If we assume even distribution throughout the year, then 2019 is on track to be close to 35k posts, between 2018 & 2017 levels, and matching 2018 for votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One could argue that the introduction of:

- Trailhead
- Lightning Flow

have made it easier for developers to avoid the "needing help route" and hence the number of new SFSE posts.

I also agree (and have postulated before) that all that can be said on VF and Apex has been said (ex new features -- e.g. Platform Events, CDC; complicated features -- e.g. custom authentication providers/SAML JIT; or little used features).  I mean, how much more can one say about bulkification and unit testing?

*That said, observationally, there seem to be a lot of LWC and DX posts that could offset the above (they being new technologies)*

Comment: I agree. I still get a regular trickle of points and comments from questions that are even six years old in some cases, and many questions and answers are revised as new technologies emerge (e.g. an answer about Batchable can now be done with Queueable). I think the network is still growing, it's just that most of the old tech has already been thoroughly covered, so it's mostly just new tech (marketing cloud, LWC, DX, etc).

Comment: @sfdcfox - some of your old answer upvotes come from me!  If I see an answer that addresses the issue that I was researching, even if not directly on point (that is, I took the time to read it), I vote it up

Comment: I don't think anything will generate more posts than @Aura components.  Now that it's being phased out, questions are dropping.

Answer (score 11):

Something I've see a lot more of recently is people asking Salesforce related questions in walled gardens. E.g. Slack channels.

I'll admit that I do it myself sometimes as well from time to time.

You can throw out a partially formed question and then refine it over time in a thread until someone can help find an answer. It works great if it is something that can be answered fairly quickly you get your answer faster.

What makes me sad about this also came up in [Official Slack Channel](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2460/102). It's a walled garden that doesn't show up in Google results. Worse still, on a free tier Slack only the most recent X number of posts are viewable. Everything else disappears.

So anything useful that gets resolved is only left in the heads of the people who participated in the thread.

I try to make a point of bringing details out of Slack channels into public Q&A posts here so they can help others over time. It's an uphill battle though.

I don't mean to pick on Slack in particular. There is definitely a place and usefulness to that type of community. They just don't have the public utility due to their closed nature.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen people use Reddit, Twitter a lot recently. It's not walled garden like Slack, but definitely reduces posts in here.

Answer (score -2):

This platform is getting worse .. even for quesiton they do the -ve votes without telling us the reason, if said we can correct and post a better question.

Comment: I believe you are mentioning [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273606/how-to-convert-string-to-listobject-for-a-test-class/273789#273789) I feel it was downvoted because question fails to specify exact error message, even comments were there requesting to provide exact error message which was as of writing this comment were not present. 

People here are striving for good quality posts.  if that was not done, It won't take any time to go down the official developer forum route.

I get downvoted a lot as well, I take it as positive criticism to improve myself.